# RGBDSlam + localization

Tags: slam, localization, navigation, kinect, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Is there a way to add a 2D map (where I will show the position of my robot) in the GUI run by `roslaunch rgbdslam kinect+rgbdslam.launch`.

Actually I just would like to reconfigure the windows of RGBDSlam GUI ,but I dont know I should do it.
Does someone have any ideas? Because it's a common wanted GUI, I think it's exist and I don't want to redevelop something already developed.

Thanks a lot
Cheers

PS: I'm using ros electric on ubuntu 11.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35770/rgbdslam-+-localization/) by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could regularly create a volumetric 3D map in [octomap_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap_server) out of the point clouds from RGBD-SLAM. octomap_server can create a downprojected 2D map for you which you can then display in RViz together with the 3D map and your robot.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brioche](https://answers.ros.org/users/2479/brioche/) on 2012-06-07**:
I've tried to install octo_server as shown on the rgbdslam wiki page but I've this error message: Unable to locate package ros-electric-octomap-mapping
Unable to locate package ros-electric-octomap-visualization
I think it's because I've just upgraded my ubuntu but I don't know what to do...

**Comment by [Chong](https://answers.ros.org/users/2273/chong/) on 2012-06-18**:
Hi AHornung, would you please tell me how to create a downprojected 2D map using octomap_server?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Brioche,
there is no way to configure RGB-D SLAM for this. Would you want to preload an existing 2d map?

Don't know if that helps, but you can display the current pose in rviz (just display the tf frame /map).

If you want to modify the code, I can point you to where the functionality would go.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1